ionic run in production mode
I am using angular 8 with ionic (mobile).
I have problem when running the application, opened in chrome browser, in production mode, while there is no problem when opening in development mode.
I realized that there are some different behaviors when running the code just by ionic server.
or after compiling with to production:
ionic build --prod --release

and do:
cd www

and run:
http-server

Only for http-server there is a problem when refreshing the page:
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:8080/mypage
HTTP ERROR 404

... while running via ionic serve there is no problem.
Also, when I open chrome dev-tools (press F12) and go to application tab.
I see that IndexDB is cleared when I am doing page refresh (that only happens for http-server).
My assumption this related to some security issues for using storage data and maybe related to few more issues.
The default for http-server, when I running it is http (not https). Should I run it as https?
I tried to configured *.crt file (by openssl):
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem

and import to certificate local manager: certlm.msc and run
http-server -S -C cert.pem -K key.pem (I copied the certificate files to the www folder) - same problem.
Nonetheless, I don't know whether run for https is must for solving the issue, or I can keep running in http.
Why is disparities between running ionic serve and http-server and how can I solve this issue?

"Should I run it as https?" - Yes....

ionic serve runs a development server that automatically handles routing and serves the application correctly, including fallback to index.html. http-server, on the other hand, does not have this built-in behavior unless you configure it. So your issues sounds like a routing issue that needs to be solved with custom logic to configure http-server to serve the index.html file.

add .htaccess file in your root folder.


How can I configure http-server that fallback will redirect to index.html? Also - 2. IndexDb is not as kept when running htttp-server. One thing kept is the authentication token. What can be done? I need an example, pls.


.htaccess - I am running on windows.
